# Programmatically controlling PyQt5 Scroll Area

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I'm looking for advice on programmatically controlling the scrollArea in PyQt5. Specifically, I would like to be able to read in a an image which is far bigger than the widow in which it is being displayed and command the scroll area to display a specific location in the image (say, the center). It looks like PyQt4 scroll area class has ensureVisible(), scrollContentsBy() and scrollBar class has a setValue attribute but I don't think those are supported in PyQt5

Comment: PyQt5's QScrollArea has those methods. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea-members.html

Comment: I think I found that out after I posted and it befuddles me that they still don't work when I try them. I'll post some code and see if that helps point to the issue.

Comment: You say: *I'll post some code*, you must provide a [mre]